# Matching all conditions ransack

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I'm trying to filter my users for their knowledge in foreign languages. I have the `LanguageSkill` model which belongs to `Member`, `Language` and `LanguageLevel`.

```
class LanguageSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :member_id, :language_id, :language_level_id
    belongs_to :member
    belongs_to :language
    belongs_to :language_level
end
```

Another important information is that `LanguageLevel` has a `difficulty` attribute (merely a integer so one can order the different language levels)

A member may have language skills in several languages, but when I query on them, I want the language and the language_level to be linked, i.e. that the language level be related to the language in question, not to any language.

The language fields partial is as follows:

```
<div class="field">
<div class="language">
    <%= select_tag :'q[language_skills_language_id_eq_all][]', options_from_collection_for_select(Language.all, 'id', 'name') %>
</div>
<div class="language_level">
    <%= select_tag :'q[language_skills_language_level_difficulty_gteq_all][]', options_from_collection_for_select(LanguageLevel.all, 'difficulty', 'name') %>
</div>
<%= link_to '#', :class => "remove_fields" do %>
    <button class="btn btn-link btn-mini">
           <i class="icon-remove"></i> <%= t('general.remove') %>
    </button>
<% end %>
 </div>
```

If I use two pieces of the above partial it generates the following SQL:

`SELECT DISTINCT "members".* FROM "members" LEFT OUTER JOIN "language_skills" ON "language_skills"."member_id" = "members"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "language_levels" ON "language_levels"."id" = "language_skills"."language_level_id" WHERE ((("language_skills"."language_id" = 38 AND "language_skills"."language_id" = 59) AND ("language_levels"."difficulty" >= 5 AND "language_levels"."difficulty" >= 3)))`

I don't know exactly what is the SQL I'd like ransack to generate, but if I input [French, Proficient] and [English, advanced] I'd like for it to fetch all the members that speak French in a Proficient (or greater) level and English in an Advanced (or greater) level.

Comment: Hi Renan, did you manage to solve this issue?I am having very similar one. If you have fixed it, could you provide your solution?Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I have not... What I'm doing right now is work the logic inside the controller, and not only using Ransack...